# How do i correct a formula tat has multiple IF statements that returns "#VALUE!" when certain cells are not populated?

Tags: excel, formula

I have an excel sheet that calculates certain information, some cells depend on others being populated. If they are not populated or have certain text in them i would like to make certain cells show a message e.g. (calculate step1 first).

I have tried but instead i get #VALUE! in each cell but when the correct data is input this changes and works correctly. I would like to get rid of the #VALUE! error.

Im not sure if IF or Even IF(OR( is the best function to use. Should i be doing this another way?

Example:

```
=IF(OR(A8="",A8="Select"),"Select Level",IF(A8="Sedentary or Light Activity",(E5*1.2),IF(A8="Lightly Active",(E5*1.375),IF(A8="Moderatetely Active",(E5*1.55),IF(A8="Very Active",(E5*1.725),IF(A8="Extra/Vigerously Active",(E5*1.9),IF(E5="","Calculate BMR")))))))
```

The above formula work fine until anything in A8 is chosen when E5 is still blank.

I wanted this to display "calculate BMR" if E5 is blank or has text that is not numerical

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your formula in iferror() like this:

```
=iferror(your_formula,0)
```

The 0 can be text if you wish ie "not_valid"...

Comment: Thanks when i try this i get too many arguments error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Well show what you entered, as I use that construct as I showed in my answer and it works fine.

Comment: =IFERROR(=IF(OR(A8="",A8="Select"),"Select Level",IF(A8="Sedentary or Light Activity",(E5*1.2),IF(A8="Lightly Active",(E5*1.375),IF(A8="Moderatetely Active",(E5*1.55),IF(A8="Very Active",(E5*1.725),IF(A8="Extra/Vigerously Active",(E5*1.9),IF(E5="","Calculate BMR",0))))))))

Even looking at it i know its wrong, would i have to save the formula and give it a name first ?

Comment: remove the "=" after the iferror( so it looks like =iferror(if( and you also need to add the ,0) at the end.

Comment: =IFERROR(=IF(OR(A8="",A8="Select"),"Select Level",IF(A8="Sedentary or Light Activity",(E5*1.2),IF(A8="Lightly Active",(E5*1.375),IF(A8="Moderatetely Active",(E5*1.55),IF(A8="Very Active",(E5*1.725),IF(A8="Extra/Vigerously Active",(E5*1.9),IF(E5="","Calculate BMR",0))))))))

that now shows too few arguments

Comment: try =IFERROR(IF(OR(A8="",A8="Select"),"Select Level",IF(A8="Sedentary or Light Activity",(E5*1.2),IF(A8="Lightly Active",(E5*1.375),IF(A8="Moderatetely Active",(E5*1.55),IF(A8="Very Active",(E5*1.725),IF(A8="Extra/Vigerously Active",(E5*1.9),IF(E5="","Calculate BMR",0)))))))),0)

Comment: Thanks but even with that i get oo few arguments, im on office 2016 if it makes a difference ?

Comment: I assumed that your original formula was correct and just put what i suggested around it - I don't have the sheet to test your original formula - if you make sure that works then add what i suggested it should work. As I said, I use that a lot and have just applied it again to a function to test exam results...

Comment: it does work as it is but when i add anything you suggested it doesnt. Im not great at excel so im sure ive not done it in the best way and thats why im getting this problem. Thanks for the help anyways. Appreciate it.